# Игнорирование пробела в начале строки

Tags: javascript

Как сделать так, что бы в функция возвращала true если строка str == str_1
даже если перед словом стоят пробелы?

```js
function STR(str,str_1) {
    
    var str_2 = str.indexOf(' ') !== -1;
    
    if(str_1 == str_2) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

console.log(STR(" Маша","Маша"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как сделать так, что бы в функция возвращала true если строка str == str_1 даже если перед словом стоят пробелы?

```js
function STR(str, str_1) {

 // Удалит все пробелы вида "  M   " 
  if (str_1.trim() === str.trim()) {
    return true
  }

  return false
}


console.log(STR(" Маша", "Маша"));
console.log(STR(" Маша", "Маша  "));
console.log(STR(" Маша", "      Маша  "));
```

---

```js
function STR(str, str_1, same_case = false) {
  // Если регистр не важен
  if (same_case && str_1.trim().toLowerCase() === str.trim().toLowerCase()) {
    return true;
  }
  // Удалит все пробелы вида "  M   " 
  if (str_1.trim() === str.trim()) {// Учитывает регистр
    return true
  }

  return false
}


console.log(STR(" Маша", "Маша"));
console.log(STR(" Маша", "Маша  "));
console.log(STR(" Маша", "      Маша  "));
console.log(STR(" other", "      Other  "));
console.log(STR(" other", "      Other  ", true)); // Only for you =)
```

[Метод trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim)

Comment: Возможно, нужно бы ещё приводить к одному регистру.

Comment: @Other Возможно.

Answer (score 1):

Строка может быть представлена и не одним словом, и это допущение весьма естественно. При этом в сравниваемых строках может быть не только несколько слов, но и несколько пробелов между последними.

```
String.prototype.equals = function(str, spc) {
   var arr = spc ? [this, str].map(i => {return i.replace(/\s+/g, ' ')}) : [this, str];
   return !!arr.reduce((i, j) => { return i.toLowerCase().trim() === j.toLowerCase().trim() ? i : NaN});
}

console.log('test'.equals('  test'));                                // true
console.log('Мама мыла раму'.equals('  мама  мыла  раму   '));       // false (не учли дополнительные пробелы между словами)
console.log('Мама мыла раму'.equals('  мама  мыла  раму   ', true)); // true (пробелы между словами учтены)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function STR(str,str_1) {
    
    if(str.trim() == str_1.trim()) {
        return true
    }
    
    return false
}

console.log(STR(" Маша","Маша"));
```